# Error establishing a database connection on wordpresss

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I got this error while running my WordPress project:

```
Error establishing a database connection This either means that the 
username and password information in your wp-config.php file is 
incorrect or we can't contact the database server at %s. This could 
mean your host's database server is down.
```

How can I solve this error? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You fix this by putting the the correct database connection information into wp-config.php. https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically add your port number in the field if you are not using 3306(Default).

[As seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilsoQ.png)